# How can I call JSON RPC in ODOO?

Tags: javascript, odoo

```js
odoo.define('second_opinion.appointment', function(require) {
    "use strict";

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var core = require('web.core');

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#view_appointment').click(function(event){
            ajax.jsonRpc("/my-appnt", 'call', {
            });

        })
    })
})
```

```py
    @http.route(['/my-appnts'], type="json", auth="user",csrf=False,methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def appointment_form(self, **post):

        apopointment = request.env['consultation'].search([])
        values=({
            'appointment':apopointment,

        })
        return request.render("second_opinion.tmp_customer_form")
```

Comment: Can you please get into more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You should see the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'JsonRequest' object has no attribute 'render'

The request handler method's result for `JSON-RPC 2` is returned as JSON-RPC [object](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object) and wrapped in the [JSON-RPC Response](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/http.py#L543).

The `render` attribute is available when using `HttpRequest`.

You made the correct call using `jsonRpc`. The issue is in the request handler.

You can find a similar example in [website_gengo](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_gengo/controllers/main.py#L33), the cotroller method is declared as following:

```
@http.route('/website/post_gengo_jobs', type='json', auth='user', website=True)
def post_gengo_jobs(self):
    request.env['base.gengo.translations']._sync_request(limit=GENGO_DEFAULT_LIMIT)
    return True
```

Then called using the following code:

```
ajax.jsonRpc('/website/post_gengo_jobs', 'call', {});
```